# Retracted close vote still appears when question is closed?

Tags: support, retracted-close-votes

I voted to close [detect the class of a property with name in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22018656/643383) (as "unclear what you're asking") but I'm fairly certain that I retracted that vote after the OP's clarifying edit. However, the question was still closed as a duplicate, and I'm listed as one of the five close votes.

I don't necessarily disagree with closing the question as a dupe, and I'm not suggesting that it should be reopened, but I'm concerned that retracting a close vote might not always be effective.

Possible bug?

Comment: How certain are you?

Comment: Given the timing of the edit and final closure, I would guess the question got closed while you were trying to retract your vote, so once it was closed,  the retraction was not allowed.  Probably a race condition that wasn't considered when the retract feature was implemented

Comment: @MartijnPieters Certain enough to suggest that there might be an issue here. I have a clear memory of doing it and don't recall noticing any indication that the retraction failed.

Comment: Now, if you can figure out how to retract a close vote and then get *six* voters (including yourself) listed on the final question as a result... That's a bug.

Answer (score 4):

According to the logs, the last close vote was submitted 5 seconds before your retraction. With events this close together, it's just a matter of who gets in first - in this case, the 5th close vote did.

If you're still sure the question isn't a duplicate, you can now vote to re-open it.

Comment: No, I'm fine with leaving it closed as a dupe. My close vote was because the question was quite vague as originally written. I was just concerned that there might be a deeper problem with the voting system. Your explanation makes a lot of sense -- thanks for checking it out.

Comment: Will the system actually notify you in *most* cases if the retraction fails due to the question getting closed aand the only reason he wasn't notified was because of the timing being so close together? Or is @Caleb's experience normal for this situation?

Comment: I don't think this situation is common, @psubsee2003. I believe it *should* tell you there are no active votes, but given how close the two events were in this particular case, all bets are off.